# Parsing JSON file and displaying in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am getting data to jquery in json form but not able to display in HTML.
I don't want use jquery to display. 
can i access jquery variable in HTML.
Please help me, if this possible.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
  $('#result').bind('input', function() {
    $.getJSON('/prescription1', {
      a: $('input[name="a"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: As you are getting the data in a JavaScript variable, then you'll have to use JavaScript to pass it to the HTML document. What is wrong with `$('#someplace').text(data.myproperty);`?

Comment: $('#someplace').text(data.myproperty); this displays the complete part.
just to be more précised, i want to control things from HTML and not from jquery.

Comment: What do you mean with *the complete part*... is that good or bad? Please provide in your question some sample data, and the result you expect. Please be as concrete as you can. Right now, this is a very vague question.

Comment: the complete json. but i need to control every key-value of json.
[{"A":1,"B":2}].
let's say i need to access only key "B" and not the complete json.

Comment: Not possible with HTML ("hypertext mark up language"). But you already use JavaScript, so why don't you want to use JavaScript.... I don't get it.

Comment: not much familiar with JavaScript, just started and wanted to avoid to have easy solution. anyway things getting clear more now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't access jquery data using HTML. HTML is a [markup language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language), this means that you can use html for

> annotating a document in a way that is syntactically
>   distinguishable from the text.

Now, if you want to avoid jQuery there is a vanilla javascript solution for your problem but you have to use javascript.

You can read this question on Quora to understand the differences between web languages: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-HTML-XML-PHP-CSS-and-JavaScript-in-layman-terms

Comment: @SatyendraSahani you can upvote my answer if you like it :-)